# Do Riddler Trophies carry over into New Game Plus on Batman: Arkham City?

Tags: batman-arkham-city

I'm a bit unclear if the Riddler trophies I've found so far will roll over into a New Game Plus. The menu option to start New Game Plus only states that gadgets and upgrades will go with you.

I'm about 250 trophies in, so don't want to lose them all I've found so far, but I'd like to get started on the New Game Plus if I can. There's also no way to make a copy of the save game I have on the Xbox 360, so I can't really experiment with this.

Comment: can't you create a second profile for game saves (I know you can (and I did) on the ps3) and play through (speedrun) it again getting a few trophies early and checking them in NG+

Comment: Can't you play both simultaneously?

Comment: @ratchetfreak Saves are tied to profiles on the Xbox 360, so no, don't believe you can. There is no option to copy a save to another empty slot either.

Comment: @Ullallulloo I don't think so. New Game Plus is an option underneath an active game, not under the main menu, so it makes it seem as if once you start it when you complete the first one, you're in the New Game Plus under that same save, not a new one.

Comment: @DoozerBlake I meant creating another profile on the 360 and starting a save from scratch on that and try it

Comment: @ratchetfreak ahh. Well, I got an answer here quicker than I would have been able to do a speedrun. ;)

Comment: @Ullallulloo after starting a New Game Plus, I see what you mean. I didn't realize it kept the 2 games separate. Had I known I that, could've just done that.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Riddler trophies do carry over. According to the description of the "Perfect Knight - Day 2" achievement in the [achievement guide](http://www.xbox360achievements.org/forum/showthread.php?t=336668) at [Xbox360Achievements.org](http://www.xbox360achievements.org):

> To 100% the game you will need the following done:
>
> - Complete the story on Normal or Hard AND New Game +
> - Complete all side-missions on BOTH playthroughs
> - Complete all riddler collectibles (data is shared on both save files)
> - Complete all upgrades through leveling up and collecting (also shared)
> - Complete all Riddler's Revenge challenges (as Batman)

I also believe that starting New Game+ does not prevent you from playing the first playthrough at the same time. I haven't done this yet, however given that there are two items in the menu (one or the normal game, another for New Game+) starting one doesn't stop the other.

Comment: As someone who's deep in Story+ at the moment, this is correct. Riddler trophies carry over (Riddler sidequest progress, however, does *not*), and you can flip between Story mode and Story+.