# Is there any reason to play Batman in story plus mode?

Tags: batman-arkham-city

I finished "Batman: Arkham City" last night. So after that, New Game mode opened as "Story+".

Why should I play that? What differences are there between this and the main story mode?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There are a few differences between the two modes.

- Enemies do more damage and have better AI
- Enemies have upgraded equipment
- No counterattack indicator

You start off with all the upgrades from your Normal/Hard playthrough. [Riddler trophies also carry over](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/34222/160).

The only "tangible" reward you get for completing the game in New Game+ mode are the two achievements **Twice Nightly**, for finishing New Game+, and **Perfect Knight - Day 2**, the requirements for which are listed in the question I just linked. Otherwise, it's just there if you want to play through the game again with more challenge.

Comment: There is also an achievement for just finishing New Game+ - "Twice Nightly", I think.

Comment: @Adeese Ah yeah, I'll edit that in, forgot that one.

Comment: Any different in story?

Comment: @Rev No, there are no differences in the story or ending.

Comment: @Ztugugigi No, that's how the normal game starts, assuming you unlocked the Catwoman DLC before you started the game.